# IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 deployment topology with Tomcat

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In developerworks paper IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation "Scalability and Hardware Sizing", There is a typical deployment with WebSphere Application Server.

[Scalability and Hardware Sizing](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/additional-documentation/scalability-hardware-sizing-7-1/)

But if choosing Tomcat as application server for MFP server farm deployment, which load balance software will been used? Are there any MFP performance report about the comparison between WebSphere application server and tomcat as MFP application server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> But if choosing Tomcat as application server for MFP server farm deployment, which load balance software will been used?

You can use whichever software you'd like. There is no enforcement in place.

> Are there any MFP performance report about the comparison between WebSphere application server and tomcat as MFP application server?

Performance tests were not run on Tomcat.